# Post kendo grid values

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

Below is the Kendo grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CS.Web.Models.People.GroupDetailModel>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .Events(e => e.DataBound("LineItems_Databound"))
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow:hidden;", @class = "normalgrid" })
  .Columns(columns =>
   {
      columns.Bound(p => p.GroupID).Hidden();
      columns.Bound(p => p.GroupName).Title("Group Name").Width(30);
      columns.Bound(p => p.Department).Title("Department Name").Width(30);
      columns.Bound(p => p.IsBlindSettingsEnable).Title("Blind Group")
        .ClientTemplate("<input  type=\"checkbox\" #= IsBlindSettingsEnable ? \"checked=checked\": \"\" # enabled=\"enabled\"  />")
        .Width(30);
      columns.Bound("Department").Title("Remove")
        .ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript:void(0)' Title='Remove'  onclick='return removeUserGroupRelation(+#=GroupID#+);'> <img alt='Remove' src='" + @Url.Content("~/Content/Images/delete_icon.png") + "' /></a>")
        .Width(30);
   })
   .Sortable()
   .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(false))
   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Ajax()
     .Read(read => read.Action("getAssignedGroups", "People")
       .Data("setRoutesValues")
   ) 

   //new { MerchantId = ViewBag.MerchantId, StartDate = Model.StartDate, EndDate = Model.EndDate }
                                )
  .TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid_1" })
)
```

Below is the javascript code

```
var userID = '@ViewBag.UserID'
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveGroupsUserDetails")',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { models: kendo.stringify($("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.view()), UserID: userID },
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

Here in my kendo grid there is checkbox column.When i check or uncheck checkbox at CLIENT sied(in browser).And Do post via give javascript $.ajax post,it will not post the values of checkboxes which I have changed on client browser,it shows the values which it was binded from server side.

so,my question is to I want updated values to post on server which are modified on client browser.

I shall be very thankfull if you provide me answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should just update your datasource on checkbox checked :

```
...
    .ClientTemplate("<input  type=\"checkbox\" #= IsBlindSettingsEnable ? \"checked=checked\": \"\" # enabled=\"enabled\" onclick='setChecked(this)' />")
...


function setChecked(cb) {
    var row = $(cb).closest("tr");
    var item = grid.dataItem(row);
    item.IsBlindSettingsEnable = cb.checked;
}
```

and now your datasource is synced with the view

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because your looking at the actual value of the dataSource and not the grid itself. Your grid is non-editable. You are manually throwing the inputs into your grid and these will not effect the dataSource.

You can take two approaches do this kind of update.

---

You can leave the grid the way you have it set up and handle this update solely though Java Script.
To do this you will need to look up all the dataItems you need to update manually with JQuery.

You can lookup all of your check boxes with in that grid that are check, then get the relevant dataItem manually. Here is a short example showing how to get a dataItem from a row in the grid.

```
//checkbox is a JQuery object referencing one of your checkboxes
var row = $(checkbox).closest("tr");
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var data = grid.dataItem(row);
```

Once you have all of your dataItems that are relevant you can then post your update. You would then have to reload your grid to get the updated status of these items.

Overall this is not the preferred way to do this kind of update with a kendo grid.

---

I suggest this second method.

This is the site where I will be pulling examples from: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing

First you will need to make your kendo grid editable `.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))`. You will not need the custom template that adds the checkbox anymore. It will automatically add them when you are editing your grid now.

You will need to then set the datasource to have an update function and have your server expect this update.

Your dataSource binding

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource        
    .Ajax()         
    .Batch(true)        
    .Read("Editing_Read", "Grid")
    .Update("Editing_Update", "Grid")
)
```

And your server side code

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Editing_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> products)
    {
        if (products != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                productService.Update(product);
            }
        }

        return Json(products.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

By returning this Json object your grid will auto update to the new values. This is the preferred way to edit a grid.